# How do I use \mathbf in an inline TeX cell?

Tags: formatting, latex

I’m pretty new to Mathematica and I’m not sure how to get `\mathbf` working in inline TeX. I am using a ‘Text’ cell and clicking the ‘Insert TeX’ button (or doing Ctrl + 4).

I am trying to get a bold upright (non-italic) character (e.g. for vectors). Here’s what I’ve tried:

| TeX | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `\mathbf a`, `\mathbf{\textnormal a}`, `\textup{\mathbf a}` | [image: a sans-serif upright non-bold ‘a’] |
| `\bf a`, `\textbf a`, `\bf{\textnormal a}`, `\textbf{\textnormal a}`, `\bf{\mathrm a}`, `\textbf{\mathrm a}` `\textup{\bf a}`, `\textup{\textbf a}` | [image: a serif italic bold ‘a’] |
| `\bf{\textnormal a}`, `\textbf{\textnormal a}`, `\bf{\textup a}`, `\textbf{\textup a}` | [image: a sans-serif italic non-bold ‘a’] |
| `\mathbf{\mathrm a}`, `\mathrm{\mathbf a}` | [image: Mathematica red box error ‘An unknown box name (Times) was sent as the BoxForm for the expression. Check the format rules for the expression.’] |
| `\mathrm{\bf a}` | [image: ‘am = 2 elax @F @bf10pta’] |
| `\mathrm{\textbf a}` | [image: ‘am = 2 × elax @F @bf10pta’] |
| `\mathbf{\textnormal a}`, `\mathbf{\textup a}` | [image: ‘am = 0 × elax @F @rm10pta’] |

I want something like this:

[image: a serif upright bold ‘a’]

I’m not sure how relevant this is but I am using macOS 13.5.1 and  Mathematica 13.3.0.0.

Comment: Do you mean in an inline TeX cell or in `MaTeX`? -- Are you sure this is the right site? It's not clear how your question relates to the Wolfram Research software product called *Mathematica*.

Comment: I mean in an inline TeX cell. I think this is the right site because I am doing this in Mathematica, and normally `\mathbf` works in TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: The practical solution here is not to try to force LaTeX, which won't be interpreted perfectly by Mathematica.  Select the letter, hit Command-I to make it upright and Command-B to make it bold. TeX cells are a relatively new feature that build on the old TeXForm. In my view they are useful if you're just getting started with Mathematica, and are not yet practised in typing math with it, but they are neither the most convenient nor the most robust way to enter math.

Comment: While I agree with Szabolcs comment, I also find this new inline TeX cell input very useful. Indeed often user already have many formulas typed in .tex and the feature allows much more easy way to  convert these formulas to notebook box structures. I am very happy with these cells and also hope they will improve in future.

Answer (score 0):

After any TeXInput inline cell via Ctrl+4 in a Text cell you may change the cell Style separatly in the Style menu for FontFamily, FontSize

[image: TeXInput]

[image: Output]

Comment: I think user wants bold  text font, not bold math mode font. So, probably you should remove \mathbf ?